# Be alerted when near to a specific Lat and Lng geopoint

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API v2 for Android, working with a MapFragment.

On a MySQL engine I have a table with pairs of latitudes and longitudes from specific road points all over my country.

So imagine I'm driving with my phone, application is open getting through onLocationChanged my current latitude and longitude almost instantly.

When I get close to one of the points of the MySQL table, I want to be alerted.
How is that possible?

I am aware of the Google Distance API, I know I can query my origin and several distinations to get several distances and then compare them, but if I have like 1k latitudes&longitudes in my SQL table this is impossible to do because of the usage limitation.

Isnt there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could let a server handle the logic for you and simply just send the coordinate to the server once in a while.

Comment: A server? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean your own backend/CMS/Server.